# getting mongodb running locally on OSX Yosemite

Tags: mac-osx, mongodb

I've installed mongodb using homebrew, but `mongod` is not running.

I'm getting this error:

```
2015-03-09T14:47:22.418+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=10510 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Sanjays-MacBook.local
2015-03-09T14:47:22.419+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.0
2015-03-09T14:47:22.419+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2015-03-09T14:47:22.419+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Darwin miniyosemite.local 14.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Mon Dec 22 23:10:38 PST 2014; root:xnu-2782.10.72~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-03-09T14:47:22.419+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2015-03-09T14:47:22.419+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-03-09T14:47:22.424+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2015-03-09T14:47:22.425+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

I think I've installed something in the wrong place, but I'm not really sure. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied` - cause looks pretty obvious

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Answer (score 2):

```
2015-03-09T14:47:22.424+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
```

Read the danged log line. Check for the existence of `/data/db/`, then check for the existence of a lock file at `/data/db/mongod.lock`. It's probably there, but owned by another user (probably root).

Comment: Is "danged" a technical term? ;-)